# WPF: Assembly resolver

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-assembly

I've got the following XAML definition:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyControls;assembly=MyProduct.MyControls"
```

Let say my product have the dll MyProduct.MyControls loaded 2 times (2 differents versions). For example version 1.0 and version 2.0.

Is there a way to explicitly resolve the assembly "MyProduct.MyControls" for the XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well according to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2028960f-9c3b-47d0-b7da-7f84f34b0df0) you won't be successful.

> I just get the confirmation that XAML parser will deliberately prevent you to use multiple version of same assemblies, which means that if the old version of assembly already exists, WPF will try use that assembly even if your XAML document is trying to reference a new version.

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx#Mapping_To_Custom_Classes_and_Assemblies ), you can specify the full name of the assembly, using the [AssemblyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.aspx) syntax :

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyControls;assembly=MyProduct.MyControls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=xyz"
```

Answer (score -1):

From reading this link on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms747086%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) site,
It looks like you use the AssemblyName to load the assembly, so it might be the case where you compile your different versions with MyProduct.MyControlsV1 as the name in the AssemblyInfo.cs for example.

So the path would become

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyControls;assembly=MyProduct.MyControlsV1"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyControls;assembly=MyProduct.MyControlsV2"
```